# How do I reset network devices in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, udev

I just installed *Ubuntu 14.04 Server* (without a GUI) running as a virtual machine (Ubuntu host). Everything is fine so far but I changed some settings regarding my networking devices. So now I tried to reset my networking settings using/deleting `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` but this file does not exist within Ubuntu 14.04.

My question is, what is **the correct way** resetting networking devices in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: What settings did you change? how did you change them?

Comment: I am using VirtualBox and I changed the second network adapter from "Internal Network" to "Host-only Adapter".

Comment: The surest way of resetting the network devices is a cold boot...  Could you please explain what you're trying to accomplish?  Use default settings for all network devices, restart network devices, resetting the devices?

Comment: It sounds like you changed the *virtual machine's* networking settings - that's a different thing from the OS's network settings, you should use select the VM in VirtualBox settings manager and revert your changes

Answer (score 0):

You could try this enter settings, and then network, and then delete and turn of network, and then turn it on again and reboot, and if it dos not self set up a new network create one, and it might work, and remember to write down the ip, based and the mac adr, and the code for the security. (Wpa).

Comment: Hi Michael, I think you are talking about Ubuntu Desktop? As I do not have any graphical user interface in my server installation I have to handle my problems using command line.